# how to get progress bar data for a running jenkins job through the API

Tags: api, jenkins

I want to use the jenkins API to get information about my current jobs. I can find information on the last build (`.../job/MyJob/lastBuild/api/xml`) but I'm not seeing the field(s) that would let me create a progress bar. I see an `estimatedDuration` field and a `building` field, but nothing that tells me how long it's already been running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the URL that gives me the information I need:

```
http://<host>/job/<jobname>/lastBuild/api/xml?tree=timestamp,estimatedDuration
```

Which yields something like:

```
<freeStyleBuild>
  <estimatedDuration>86126</estimatedDuration>
  <timestamp>1350615637401</timestamp>
</freeStyleBuild>
```

Comment: I noticed that this only shows for when the build is complete, is there a feed to get live updates on the percent complete of the build? For instance when a person initiates a build i can emulate the jenkins progress bar on another website?

Answer (score 7):

For me is also working by getting a json:

```
http://<host>/job/<jobname>/lastBuild/api/json?tree=executor[progress]
```

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question while trying to retrieve the percentage. As I figured out a solution, I thought I would post it here.

The response includes two fields, `timestamp` (time the job started) and `estimatedDuration` (milliseconds).

If you take the current time, you can subtract the `timestamp` from the current time. This will give you the number of milliseconds since the job started. Using this calculated value, you can compare it with the `estimatedDuration` field and thus determine the percentage complete.

So the formula would be (where data is a JSON object of the returned data):

```
Console.log(" complete: " + Math.round((new Date().getTime() - data.timestamp) / data.estimatedDuration * 100) + "%");
```

Your using XML and not JSON, but I'm sure it's a similar structure.

I'm using the following lib in node.js: https://github.com/jansepar/node-jenkins-api

My logic is:

```
var jenkinsapi = require('./lib/jenkins');

var jenkins = jenkinsapi.init("http://jenkins.myServer.com:8080");

jenkins.last_result('/myProj', function(err, data) {

  if(err) {
    console.log("last result kitchen_ellipse: ERROR (last result): " + data.statusCode);
    return;
  }

  console.log("progress " + data.fullDisplayName + " number: #" + data.number + 
          + " complete: " + 
            Math.round((new Date().getTime() - data.timestamp) / 
                       data.estimatedDuration * 100) + "%"
          + " result: " + data.result);
});
```

Comment: I keep getting 404 using the last_result() call, if i have a job named, 'jobA', how do you pass it to last_result? Because if i use the function, last_build_info, i just pass it as last_build_info('jobA'), but if i do last_result('jobA') or last_result('/jobA') i get 404.

Comment: Sorry BLang, it's been a long time since I last looked at this. I had a quick look through my old lib and the above is how I was doing it. You can see my old code at https://github.com/jamesjenner/Vor/blob/master/lib/server/jenkins.js. It was working back in those days. Just no idea now a days sorry.

Comment: no worries, i actually figured out a solution and when i finish/ get it stable, ill be posting to the thread i created here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455608/live-feed-of-jenkins-job-progress-bar

Answer (score 2):

use following :

```
 http://<host>/job/<jobname>/lastBuild/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=*/executor/progress/text()
```

this will return you the progress in percentage

ex : 27

similarly you can get other parameters like user, id(build number), timestamp etc.

you can find them using following url:

```
http://<host>/job/<jobname>/lastBuild/api/xml?depth=1
```

above url returns an xml where all the required parameter ,from last build, are listed.