# Live feed of jenkins job progress bar

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am looking for a way to display the build progress bar of a build in jenkins to be able to display on my application. I havent been able to find any API calls to narrow this down, so i am looking for direction!

This was the closest post i found on this task, but it only shows you a duration after the build is complete.

[how to get progress bar data for a running jenkins job through the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944403/how-to-get-progress-bar-data-for-a-running-jenkins-job-through-the-api)

Comment: Since someone up voted this, just wanted to update, I have figured this out, and i will post my solution when finished and it is stable.